# intellij 14 does not show all open files

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

In Intellij 13 the main code window showed all my open classes (their names flowed onto multiple lines), but now in Intellij 14 it shows a little dropdown and only shows them on one line. Is there a setting I can change to get it to flow to multiple lines again?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In Preferences, under `Editor > General > Editor Tabs`, untick the "Show tabs in single row" option.

Comment: For anyone who is wondering how to get "Preferences", press `ctrl + alt + s`

Comment: Supplement：
Macos: cmd+, search `tab limit`. Closing Policy, it's up to your used.

Answer (score 33):

#### IntelliJ IDEA 15

- **File** > **Settings...** or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

  [image: File Settings]
- **Editor** > **General** > **Editor Tabs** > **Show tabs in single row**

  [image: Editor General Editor Tabs Show tabs in single row]

  If your work with a small number of file types, I recommend you to check the **Hide file extension in editor tabs**, too. I usually work with Java and XML files and I can easily recognize them because only the Java file names are in camel case.

Answer (score 0):

Open Files ->Settings ->Editor -> General ->Editor Tabs->check show tables in a single row option

you can also choose other options like hiding tabs etc....

Answer (score 0):

**For IntelliJ IDEA version 2023.3.2 and later, the options have been updated.**

- Click Multiple rows

[image: Multiple Rows]